# Read Protobuf Serialization of StanfordNLP Output in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, stanford-nlp

I would like to output the StanfordNLP results in protobuf (since its size is much smaller) and read the results back in python. How should I do that?

I followed the instruction [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html) to output the results serialized with `ProtobufAnnotationSerializer`, like this:

```
java -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" \
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
-annotators tokenize,ssplit \
-file input.txt \
-outputFormat serialized \
-outputSerializer \
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer
```

Then use `protoc` to compile the `CoreNLP.proto`, which comes with the source code of StanfordNLP, into python modules like this:

```
protoc --python_out=. CoreNLP.proto
```

Then in python I read the files back like this:

```
import CoreNLP_pb2
doc = CoreNLP_pb2.Document()
doc.ParseFromString(open('input.txt.ser.gz', 'rb').read())
```

The parsing fails with the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-213-d8eaeb9c2048> in <module>()
      1 doc = CoreNLP_pb2.Document()
----> 2 doc.ParseFromString(open('imed/s5_tokenized/conv-00000.ser.gz', 'rb').read())

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/message.pyc in ParseFromString(self, serialized)
    183     """
    184     self.Clear()
--> 185     self.MergeFromString(serialized)
    186 
    187   def SerializeToString(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.pyc in MergeFromString(self, serialized)
   1092         # The only reason _InternalParse would return early is if it
   1093         # encountered an end-group tag.
-> 1094         raise message_mod.DecodeError('Unexpected end-group tag.')
   1095     except (IndexError, TypeError):
   1096       # Now ord(buf[p:p+1]) == ord('') gets TypeError.

DecodeError: Unexpected end-group tag.
```

UPDATE:

I asked the author of the serializer Gabor Angeli and got the answer. The protobuf objects were written to the files with `writeDelimitedTo` in [this line](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/83f9965d85851dff4134a31425f7c095e6711ca7/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java#L180). Changing it to `writeTo` would make the output files readable in Python.

Comment: What version of protoc are you running?  `protoc --version`

Comment: @sberry: it outputs "libprotoc 3.0.0".

Comment: That may also be an issue (not sure which version was used to generate the .java files) but see my answer first because that is a problem too.

Comment: @sberry: The proto file does not include a proto version specification, and the compiler compiled it as proto2, which is correct because the proto file has the "optional" keyword.

Comment: @sberry: I got the answer from asking Gabor and I put it in the post. Thank you still for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to have come up again, so I figured I'd write up a proper answer. The root of the issue is that the proto is written using Java's `writeDelimitedTo` method, which Google has not implemented for Python. A workaround would be to use the following method to read the proto file (assuming the file is not gziped -- you can replace `f.read()` with the appropriate code to unzip the file as appropriate):

```
from google.protobuf.internal.decoder import _DecodeVarint
import CoreNLP_pb2

def readCoreNLPProtoFile(protoFile):
  protos = []
  with open(protoFile, 'rb') as f:
    # -- Read the file --
    data = f.read()
    # -- Parse the file --
    # In Java. there's a parseDelimitedFrom() method that makes this easier
    pos = 0
    while (pos < len(data)):
      # (read the proto)
      (size, pos) = _DecodeVarint(data, pos)
      proto = CoreNLP_pb2.Document()
      proto.ParseFromString(data[pos:(pos+size)])
      pos += size
      # (add the proto to the list; or, `yield proto`)
      protos.append(proto)
  return protos
```

The file `CoreNLP_pb2` is compiled from the [CoreNLP.proto](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/CoreNLP.proto) file in the repo with the command:

```
protoc --python_out /path/to/output/ /path/to/CoreNLP.proto
```

Note that as of writing this (version 3.7.0) the format is proto2, not proto3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution in Golang, assume the raw data is "data" and parsed to "msg":

```
import (
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protowire"
)

func CoreNLPUnmarshal(data []byte, msg 
protoreflect.ProtoMessage) error {
    bs, n := protowire.ConsumeBytes(data)
    if n < 0 {
        return protowire.ParseError(n)
    }
    return proto.Unmarshal(bs, msg)
}
```

Comment: The question requires an answer in Python